# Fancybox loading animation does not trigger

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there any particular reason why fancybox function

```
$.fancybox.showActivity();
```

throws an error in my script? Is there a specific order in which the functions need to be called? The function is intended to show the loading image before the content is loaded to the popup. Here's my code:

```
$(".info_button").click(function () {

    var pictid_browse = $(this).parent().find('#pictid').val();
    $.fancybox.showActivity();
    $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.html",
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                data: ({f:"get_info",pictid:pictid_browse}),
                success: function(data){
    $.fancybox({
                    'autoDimensions'    : false,
                'width'                 : 950,
                'height'                : 'auto',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });
                $.fancybox({content:data,'autoDimensions':true,'scrolling':'no',});


    }
    });

    return false;
    });
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
        F.open.apply( this, arguments );
    } has no method 'showActivity'
```

or

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$.fancybox.showActivity()')
```

Fancybox version: 2.1.3

**UPDATE:**

I have no clue what is going on but if I place the

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();
```

outside of

```
$(".info_button").click(function () {
```

then it fires and shows the animation. But I need it to happen once the item of a class '.info_button' i clicked

The following solution does not seem to solve the problem either:

```
    $(".info_button").bind('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
}
```

The research shows that the loading is triggered if the following code is deleted:

```
 $.fancybox({
content:data,
                'autoDimensions'    : true,
            'width'                 : 'auto',
            'height'                : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'scrolling':'no'
        });
```

This may mean that the fancybox does not work fine when included inside ajax function, but why-I have no clue

Comment: Updated my answer, pls comment on it if you update your question.

Comment: Are u seeing any kind of errors now? Maybe try commenting out everything inside .click function and leave only the `$.fancybox.showLoading();` line. What happens?

Comment: But if you look into firebugs console ( https://getfirebug.com/ ) do you see any error messages ( without commenting everything out )? It could be that the `data` is not right for fancybox and it errors out. Or if you run this local the ajax call would be completed instantly, so you can't expect to see the loading image. I helped you out on the core question, and this site is not for tutoring someone.

Comment: I understand, but there are no js errors and the code simply does not show loading image. I will try to rebuild the ajax call to suit fancybox then. I appreciate your help anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apidock on [fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/api) is kinda outdated ( its for 1.x.y ).

So if you use:

- the older 1.x.y you want to go for:  `$.fancybox.showActivity();`
- the newer 2.x.y you want to go for:  `$.fancybox.showLoading();`

You can find for documentation for 2.x.y [fancyapss.com](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) documentation and stuff. They keeping up the site "because the two versions (1.x and 2.x) have different license schemes" ( thx to [@JFK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk) ). You can report it, mb you get a gold star from them :)

========= **Answer after question update** ==========

I cant be sure without seeing the full html and js but You could try:

```
$(".info_button").bind('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thats is a good tip! Yet I still can't make the loading icon appear. I have bo js error this time though...

Comment: What is your Version number of fancybox?

Comment: `The apidock on fancybox.net is kinda outdated` ... well, it's not. [fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/) is for v1.3.4 and below while [fancyapps.com](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) is for the new version 2.x and above. Fancybox v1.3.x API options, methods and callbacks are not compatible with v2.x and vice versa .... use the right options for the version you are using.

Comment: I think now, you are missing the image for the loading icon. Are you sure you copied it as well? `fancybox_loading.gif`

Comment: `They keeping up the site cause of SEO I think` : the reason for keeping two sites is because the two versions (1.x and 2.x) have different license schemes.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
    <style>
     #fancybox-loading{z-index:999999999;}
    </style>



     <script>
                       $.fancybox({
                                'href'          :your_url,  
                                'width'         : 900,
                                'height'        : 600,
                                'scrolling' : 'auto',
                                'type'              : 'iframe',
                                'titleShow'     : false,
                                'onComplete' : function() {
                                    $.fancybox.showActivity();
                                    $('#fancybox-frame').load(function() {
                                        $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                                    });
                                }
                        })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be in the double fancybox call. Working code below:

```
    $('.info_button').bind('click', function() {
    var pictid_browse = $(this).parent().find('#pictid').val();
    $.fancybox.showLoading();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        url:"ajax.html",
        data:({f:"get_info",pictid:pictid_browse}),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox({content:data,'autoDimensions':true,'scrolling':'no'});
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```